# Is it possible to use add_submenu_page() to add an item that's a link to edit another page?

Tags: add-submenu-page

I've recently discovered add_submenu_page and was pleased to be able to add my own page under a specific post type.  I'm using a callback function to output some HTML directly

```
/**
 * Display callback for the submenu page.
 */
function homeslides_ref_page_callback() { 
?><h1>Curate Social Media</h1> 
<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;min-height:600px" src="/mypage">    </iframe>
<?php
}
```

I would now like to make a separate callback for other custom post types, but one that lets me effectively make a shortcut to edit a particular page. For example, I have a custom post type called Careers, and within Careers I'd like to add a menu item that links to the edit page for a separate page.

It's not immediately obvious to me how I'd do this - does anyone have experience of this?

Comment: You'd need to try this first, but I'm sure you can use an absolute URL as the `$menu_slug` argument with no callback e.g. `add_submenu_page( 'parent-slug', 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'capability', get_edit_post_link( $post_id ) );`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This does indeed work, except that `get_edit_post_link` outputs an absolute URL, which is then appended to the domain. To get this to work, I had to replace out the hostname - ie. 
    `add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=work', 'Edit Work', 'Edit Landing Page', 'manage_options', str_replace($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'',get_edit_post_link( $workpage->ID ) ));`  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {      
    $('#toplevel_page_display_strategies ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('current')
    $('#toplevel_page_display_strategies').removeClass('wp-not-current-submenu')
    $('#toplevel_page_display_strategies').addClass('wp-has-current-submenu')

} );
```